# chosenHandlers is not a function error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I've been trying to make my first node.js project with a Skillshare teacher, however, while he doesn't run into this error, I did. I've read the code over but there is very little that I can do when I am a beginner to node.js. Here is the code. I would appreciate it if you can help me debug what is going on. I thank you in advance.

```js
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    //parse the URL
    var parsedURL = url.parse(req.url, true);

    //get the path
    var path = parsedURL.pathname;
    var trimmedPath = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '')

    //queryString
    var queryStringObject = parsedURL.query;

    //get the HTTP method
    var method = req.method.toLowerCase();

    //get the headers as an object
    var headers = req.headers;

    //get the payload, if any
    var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8');
    var buffer = '';
    req.on('data', function(data) {
        buffer += decoder.write(data); 
    }); 
    req.on('end', function() {
        buffer += decoder.end();

        //Choose the handler this request should go to
        var chosenHandler = typeof(router[trimmedPath]) !=='underfined' ? router[trimmedPath] : handlers.notfound;

        //Construct the data object to send the handler
        var data = {
            'trimmedPath' : trimmedPath,
            'queryStringObject' : queryStringObject,
            'method' : method,
            'headers' : headers,
            'payload' : buffer
        };

        //Route the request to the handler
        chosenHandler(data, function(statusCode, payload) {
            statusCode = typeof(statusCode) == 'number' ? statusCode: 200;

            payload = typeof(payload) == 'object' ? payload : {};

            var payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);
            res.writeHead(statusCode);

            res.end(payloadString)

            //Log the path
            console.log('Returning this respond: ', statusCode, payloadString);

        });        
    });
});


server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000")
});


//define the handler
var handlers = {};


//sample handler
handlers.sample = function(data,callback) {
    callback(406, {'name' : 'sample handler'})
};

//not found handler
handlers.notfound = function(data, callback) {
    callback(404);
};


//define a request router

var router = {
    'sample' : handlers.sample

};
```

Comment: try this `var chosenHandler = router[trimmedPath] || handlers.notfound;`

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @EvertvdH. that worked! Thank you! But ... why didn't `var chosenHandler = typeof(router[trimmedPath]) !=='underfined' ? router[trimmedPath] : handlers.notfound;` work as intended? That's exactly what the instructor showed in his video. I copied it, struggled to find my mistake, and eventually found this thread. I'm just wondering why it worked for the instructor and not for @MaxPan and I. A change in node.js maybe? Anyway, thanks again for the help!!! And Max, thanks for asking the original question. You saved me the effort of asking it and waiting for a response. :)

Comment: `router[trimmedPath]) !=='underfined'` has a typo in there. `'underfined'` should be `undefined`. I just simplified it a bit more to make it more readable.

Comment: Hmm. I doubt mine also said `underdefined`. That's not a typo I usually make (though I make dozens of other typos!) and I didn't copy/paste the code. So that still doesn't explain if there was something wrong with the original ternary approach. I did get mine working using your simplified code. Maybe I'll go back after I finish the next section of the tutorial and see if I can get the original ternary to work. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var chosenHandler = router[trimmedPath] || handlers.notfound;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same project and in my case:

`const  chosenHandler = typeof(router[trimmedPath]) !== 'undefined' ? router[trimmedPath] : handlers.notfound;`

did  not work as well as

`const chosenHandler = router[trimmedPath] || handlers.notfound;`

but when I changed into:

`const  chosenHandler = typeof(router[trimmedPath]) !== 'undefined' ? router[trimmedPath] : handlers.notFound;`

and

`const  chosenHandler = router[trimmedPath] || handlers.notFound;`

both work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

chosenHandler is not a function but a variable. try this:

[project code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvvrY.png)

Comment: Please do not share pictures of code. Instead, please include a code block so others can copy your example.

Comment: `chosenHandler` is a variable _which contains a function_. The original code is correctly invoking the chosen handler. Your answer finds the handler defined by routing and then _immediately overwrites it_ with a custom handler, instead of invoking the chosen handler.